# UITextView text not starting from top

Tags: iphone, uitextview

I have a `UITextView`. I want its text to start from top but I it is not coming from top. Please have a look at my code :

```
UITextView *myTextView = [[UITextView alloc] init];
myTextView.frame = rect;
myTextView.editable = NO;
myTextView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:MAIN_FONT_SIZE];
myTextView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
myTextView.text = sourceNode.label;
myTextView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeAll;
[cell.contentView addSubview:myTextView];
[myTextView sizeToFit];
[self alignTextToTopTextView:myTextView];
```

**alignTextToTopTextView**:

```
-(void)alignTextToTopTextView :(UITextView*)textView{

    CGRect frame = textView.frame;
    frame.size.height = textView.contentSize.height;
    textView.frame = frame;
}
```

**Please see the below screenshot**.

`UITextView` is on the right side.

[image]

Comment: @Nitish, font size of both textview is same???

Comment: Left hand side view is UILabel and right hand side view is UITextView. Yes size for both is same.

Comment: Any issue in changing both as uilabels or both as uitextviews?

Comment: I think it is the normal behavior of the UITextView. What you can do is align UILabel according to the UITextView !!!

Comment: I have to keep right view as UITextView as I need to detect strings for which I am using dataDetectors. There is no second point on changing it to UILabel. The left should has to be UILabel.

Comment: ok.from where u r getting rect? myTextView.frame = rect;Try to reduce that y value in the rect

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Set the Content Inset like this in your UITextView

```
youtextView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-7.0,0.0,0,0.0);
```

Adjust the Top value the way you want. this shoud fix your problem.

**EDIT:**

If you're having issues with iOS7 or above, try using...

> [yourTextView setContentOffset: CGPointMake(x,y) animated:BOOL];

Comment: looks good, but do you know how to calculate the top inset, rather than setting a fixed value?

Comment: any way to handle this for UITextView with variable font size?

Comment: Also work with `User Defined Runtime Attributes` in the Storyboard.

Answer (score 47):

in the viewDidLoad method add

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
```

Comment: If I add this line, and the text is long, this won't make any sense at all. So that I won't came here for a solution.

Comment: @crazy_phage it works well even with long text, maybe you have some other constraints that disable this solution for you

Comment: yeah,maybe, I was using sb that time, also with some weird code.

Comment: This is the best solution for Swift, autolayout with and without storyboards. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Best answer ever. I tried all other solutions, only this one does the trick. Thanks

Comment: This is the best answer! Works with Xcode 7.3.1 and Swift 2.0.

Comment: This prevented text in my textFields from moving down when typing. Thank you

Answer (score 24):

I did this way. When scroll disable, the the text loaded from top. After load than enable scroll.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
myTextView.scrollEnabled = NO;  
}       
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewDidAppear:animated];
myTextView.scrollEnabled = YES;
}
```

Comment: This is a solution. (iOS10.2 with swift3)

Comment: This worked for me in iOS 11
It seems strange this is necessary.

Answer (score 22):

None of the existing solutions helped, but this **helped**:

Objective-C:

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [self.yourTextView setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:NO];
}
```

**Swift 3**:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    textView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), animated: false)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is what I use

```
textView.textContainerInset = 
    UIEdgeInsetsMake(
        0,
        -textView.textContainer.lineFragmentPadding, 
        0, 
        -textView.textContainer.lineFragmentPadding
    )
;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
self.yourTextView.scrollEnabled = NO;

self.yourTextView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Code-Only answers are not considered as good answers. Please improve your answer by providing more context and explanations.

Comment: please write some explanation along with the code. code only answers are generally discouraged in SO --Review

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
   [textField addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"contentSize" options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew) context:NULL];
   [super viewDidLoad];
}

-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
   UITextView *tv = object;
   //Center vertical alignment
   //CGFloat topCorrect = ([tv bounds].size.height - [tv contentSize].height * [tv zoomScale])/2.0;
   //topCorrect = ( topCorrect < 0.0 ? 0.0 : topCorrect );
   //tv.contentOffset = (CGPoint){.x = 0, .y = -topCorrect};

   //Bottom vertical alignment
   CGFloat topCorrect = ([tv bounds].size.height - [tv contentSize].height);
    topCorrect = (topCorrect <0.0 ? 0.0 : topCorrect);
    tv.contentOffset = (CGPoint){.x = 0, .y = -topCorrect};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer

in Swift

```
termsTextView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, -220)
```

in Objective-C

```
[termsTextView setContentOffset: CGPointMake(0,-220) animated:NO];
```

Comment: Your Swift code is not right version of Objective-C. It should be 'yourTextView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: -220), animated: true)'

Comment: This is the correct code for me it worked! Well done Sameera

Comment: Suggested edit:  
`myTextView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, -myTextView.contentSize.height)`  
Rationale: The OP's UITextView is called `myTextView`, not `termsTextView`. And pulling the height dynamically makes the answer more useful to other readers (I hope), e.g. those that make UITextViews in the Interface Builder.

Answer (score 0):

This happens after I setting the `autoresizingMask` property of the `UITextView` in both iOS 7 and 8.

I found a optional workaround:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [yourTextView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, 0, yourTextView.contentSize.width, 10) animated:NO];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want text views laid out in storyboards to load properly without adding view controller management, this'll do it (iOS 12, Swift 4.2):

```swift
final class UITopLoadingTextView: UITextView {

    var shouldEnableScroll = false

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        shouldEnableScroll = isScrollEnabled
        self.isScrollEnabled = false
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        isScrollEnabled = shouldEnableScroll
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

swift 4 solution:

```
self.textView.scrollRangeToVisible(NSMakeRange(0, 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

I just set the Y content offset to zero when I initialize the textview:

```
let textview: UITextView = .init(frame: .zero)
// initialize
textview.contentOffset.y=0
```